# How to know when to contact refresh token endpoint?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm trying to build a web application and a mobile application, so i decided to handle authentifications with JWT.
I want to know where to store refresh token on server and on client, and also when do i know when i need to call the refresh token endpoint from my client side ?
I use local strategy (email and password).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you will have a database that your server application works with, so you would want to store the JWT with a user's other information in that database. Any database system will work as long as you can retrieve a user's information from the database using a provided JWT in a call to the server. In order to get up and running quickly, I would recommend trying out a database like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) or something similar.

If you are already using local storage to maintain the user's email and password, then you can use the same strategy to store the JWT that the client receives from the server. Although, I would not recommend storing the email and password in the local storage of the browser since that is a huge security vulnerability. The best thing to do is store the email and password in the database along with the JWT and you can look that information up on the server when necessary given a specified JWT. But that information should never be stored locally on the client.

Since every JWT has a corresponding expiration date, you can use a bit of code on the client side to check the expiration date and time and figure out when you should make an attempt to refresh your JWT for a new one with an extended expiration date. Check out this [documentation](https://jwt.io/) for details on various packages that can be used to interact with JWTs. The expiration date field in the JWT is called `exp`, so search for that in the provided documentation link.